# Logging Feature Usage in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm interested in logging information about what features users are using in my Rails app.  I know of existing Gems for performance metrics, logging user activity (e.g., public_activity), or more general analytics (e.g., google analytics), but what I'm looking for is a bit difference.

For example, if I have a feature that enables users to export their data, what service would you recommend to keep track of how many users (and which users) are using this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Simple option would of course be to write a another model (for example Activity) that keeps track of the usages:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    # attributes for resource (export, in this case), action type (Excel export) and user id
end
```

Then it could be applied with *before_filter* on your ExportController:

```
ExportController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :register_activity

    def register_activity
       ExportActivity.create { } # Apply the params here
    end
end
```

This way also provides you with the possibility to easily access the data and make statistics about it as you have it under your own control.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but would this require to have a new model for every time of activity I want to monitor?  I would probably want different attributes for each type of activity, so this seems like it could get unwieldy...

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you need to do something fancy with those attributes, this isn't going to be enough as those will most likely be strings.